# How to solve `Segmentation fault` error on every sudo action?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I newly installed (again) Raspbian from Noobs and updated, upgraded and dist-upgraded. After all of this i reboot my Pi and tried to `sudo su` and got

```
Segmentation fault
```

error. Tried rebooting and re-installing OS but every time when i distro upgrade it's happening.

What's the matter my Pi ? I searched on board and google but i only get it's a SD Card problem but when i did not upgrade distro, i can install apache etc and reboot and no problem after it.

Is my SD Card corrupted or something wrong with distro upgrading ?

Note: My upgrading way is;

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

BTW: I cant even `sudo halt`... it's giving me same error.

---

**Edit**: My `/etc/apt/sources.list` content

```
 deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
 # Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
 #deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

Comment: It's really weird. Can you show us your `/etc/apt/sources.list` ?

Comment: @Huczu Updated answer with sources.list content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I formatted SD Card with [SD Card Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/) and uploaded (*wrote*) via [Win32DiskImager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) Raspbian Lite img and tried but same error. And I tried normal (*not light*) version too but still same error. Somehow my SD Card is corrupted.

I had same SD Card (*same brand, same size*) and tried Raspbian normal and it worked. I do not know still what is the exact problem but i know SD Cards can be corrupt.

Comment: Also formatted with sd card formatter and have the same symptoms. wget msg is just: "Speicherzugriffsfehler"

Answer (score 3):

The contents of your SD card is corrupt.

The only safe solution is to re-write the SD card from scratch.

Perhaps do a direct install of Raspbian Lite?

Comment: I already re-wrote multiple times and same error again and again. I'm not in an isolated network or something btw... What is the difference between Raspbian vs Raspbian Lite ?

Comment: @ahmetertem I have to assume you have a faulty SD card.  Raspbian Lite uses a lot less SD card space.  A lot of bloat has been removed.  I don't know what though.